# Vue Production Build Dist Folder does not run the Vue app

Tags: vue.js, vite, npm-package

I have a question regarding the project I've created with Vue.js.

We know that when we want to create a production build, we must run 'npm run build,' and it will generate a 'dist' folder.

My question is, why does it only display a blank screen when I open the 'index.html' in the 'dist' folder, and upon checking the console, it shows some errors?

However, when I access it through the command line by inputting 'serve -s dist,' it provides me with an address, and now it works!

I'm curious why one method doesn't work while the other one does.

Comment: When you open `index.html` in your browser, the browser only loads that file, all the related Javascript files etc are not available to the page. Otherwise random webpages could read random files on your computer and that's not what anyone wants. Running `serve` starts a local webserver which makes the rest of the required files available too.

Comment: @Etheryte Your comment seems to be the answer, I suggest you post it as such.